# Data scraping movie reviews

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape the text of reviews and their respective rating from a movie site for my project using Python. The only problem is that the rating on this website is given in stars as follows: if a movie has a 6/10 rating then somewhere in the html code we will find 6 full stars images and 4 empty stars images. I don't know how to extract this rating as a text.
I am also a newbie with python so if anybody can help me with a piece of code where you extract the text of reviews and their rating I would be very grateful.

This is the url of reviews of the movie avatar: https://www.cinemagia.ro/filme/avatar-17818/reviews/?pagina=1&order_direction=DESC

Comment: Did you forget to post the code you're having trouble with?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a loop and cycle through the star images and increase the count for each loop. This will count each instance of:

```
<img src="https://static.cinemagia.ro/img/star_full.gif">
```

I wouuld probably use selenium to fin the xpath location of the stars

If you have a sample of your code I can be more specific?

Comment: Nope; until now I used a data scraper extension on chrome but now I want to do this in python. I would be very grateful if you gave me your personal idea of a code that does this. As I said I am a newbie in python and this is very overwhelming for me, even after watching a lot of Youtube videos and reading about Beautiful Soup and all that

Comment: I wont be writing the code for you but I can point you in a direction.
Selenium is at home scraping relatively more complex, dynamic pages at a price of higher computational resource cost. Beautiful Soup is easier to get started with, and although more limited in the websites it can scrape, it's ideal for smaller projects where the source pages are well structured.
At first glance I see this scrape as a more complex task would recomend you to try selenium.

Comment: I got some help on another website: rating = 0

rawRating = soup.find("span", {"class": "stelutze"}).find_all("img")

for i in rawRating:

if "star_full.gif" in i.get("src"):

rating += 1

print(rating)    The only thing is that this only shows me the score of the first review. I reckon that I have to use soup.find_all('span', class_='stelutze') instead and make ratings a list but I can't figure it out. Btw why does my comment get posted when I hit enter, I just want to get to the next line :D

Comment: If you press "Shift" + "enter" you can make a new line :)
I will comeback to you question later when I have time :)